# How to add "comments" part during SSH Protocol Version Exchange?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I want to set up or configure an OpenSSH server, to pass optional comments during Protocol Version Exchange and observe the client behavior as stated below.

**RFC format:**

```
SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
```

By default. I could see the following message from the server side during the protocol version exchange. Now I want to add comment string as stated in RFC.

```
24 6.145764 192.168.0.5 192.168.10.2 SSHv2 90 Server: Protocol (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1)
```

EX: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1 **comment**

How to add or configure the OpenSSH server to share comment string along with Proto and Software version during the exchange?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Kenster updated the question with more details.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question...?

Comment: Here is my question **How to add or configure the OpenSSH server to share comment string along with Proto and Software version during the exchange?**

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of OpenSSH `sshd` support a configuration option *VersionAddendum* which sets the comment portion of the server version string. See the documentation [here](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#VersionAddendum). The feature was added sometime in between OpenSSH 6.0 and 6.6.